# How to solve this LinkageError in Tomcat 7 using Axis 1

Tags: java, tomcat, axis

I have a running old Java Web Service written in Apache Axis. 
I am coding a client application which will send some data to this SOAP-style deployed service.
I am not able to connect to service due to a LinkageError.

This is my client call to web service:

```
    EBServicesBar remoteService = null;
    // try {

    GlobalConfiguration cg = globalConfigurationDao.findAll().get(0);

    URL url = new URL(cg.getUrlServicoAutbank());
    QName qNameServiceName = new QName("url here", cg.getQnameServicoAutbank());

    EBServicesBarService service = new EBServicesBarServiceLocator(
            cg.getWsdlServicoAutbank(), qNameServiceName);

    try {
        remoteService = service.getEBServicesBar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error( e.getMessage());
    }
```

---

// Stubs here generated by Axis thru WSDL definition

```
/**
 * EBServicesBarService.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

package br.com.autbank;

public interface EBServicesBarService extends javax.xml.rpc.Service {
    public java.lang.String getEBServicesBarAddress();
    public br.com.autbank.EBServicesBar getEBServicesBar()
            throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
    public br.com.autbank.EBServicesBar getEBServicesBar(java.net.URL portAddress)
            throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
}
```

---

```
public interface EBServicesBar extends java.rmi.Remote {

    public br.com.autbank.TOIntegracaoRetornoTransfCC transfCC(
            java.lang.String coligada, java.lang.String agencia,
            java.lang.String codColigadaDeb, java.lang.String codAgenciaDeb,
            java.lang.String nroContaDeb, java.lang.String codColigadaCre,
            java.lang.String codAgenciaCre, java.lang.String nroContaCre,
            java.lang.String dataMovto, java.math.BigDecimal valor,
            java.lang.String tarifado, java.lang.String origem,
            java.lang.String sisOrigem, java.lang.String validaPtoCorte,
            java.lang.String codUsuario, java.lang.String validaSaldoCC,
            java.lang.String historicoDeb, java.lang.String historicoCred,
            java.lang.String complHistorico, java.lang.String autorizaLanctoRetro,
            java.lang.String numDocto, java.lang.String canalEntrada)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException, br.com.autbank.TEException;

    public br.com.autbank.TOIntegracaoRetornoTED requisitaTED(java.lang.String agencia,
            java.lang.String codEvento, java.lang.String horaVencto,
            java.math.BigDecimal valor, java.lang.String agenciaDeb,
            java.lang.String contaDeb, java.lang.String bancoCredito,
            java.lang.String agenciaCred, java.lang.String contaCred,
            java.lang.String tipoContaCred, java.lang.String cnpjCpfCliCred,
            java.lang.String nomeCliCred, java.lang.String finalidade,
            java.lang.String historico, java.lang.String tarifado,
            java.lang.String validaPtoCorteSpb, java.lang.String codUsuario,
            java.lang.String cnpjCpfCliRem, java.lang.String nomeCliRem,
            java.lang.String cnpjCpfCliCred2, java.lang.String nomeCliCred2,
            java.lang.String codIdentdTransf, java.lang.String origem,
            java.lang.String sisOrigem, java.lang.String dataVencto,
            java.lang.String tipoPessoaCred, java.lang.String prioridade,
            java.lang.String dataAgendPag, java.lang.String debAutorizado,
            java.lang.String sensibilizaCC, java.lang.String nroBoleto,
            java.lang.String codCliente, java.lang.String tipoPessoaInvest,
            java.lang.String cnpjCpfInvest, java.lang.String nomeRzSocialInvest,
            java.lang.String complementoHistorico, java.lang.String numOrigem,
            java.lang.String subSistemaO, java.lang.String canalEntrada,
            java.lang.String numContratoOpeCred, java.lang.String modOpeCredPortd,
            java.lang.String ispbCred, java.lang.String nuPortdd,
            java.lang.String ispbPrestd, java.lang.String numBenfcINSSCliCredtd,
            java.lang.String tpBenfcINSS, java.lang.String numProtAvebcINSS,
            java.lang.String tpOpEmprtConsigd, java.math.BigDecimal vlrCredConsigd,
            java.math.BigDecimal vlrTarBcoCredtd)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException, br.com.autbank.TEException;
  }
```

The error is

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
>   field "service" the class loader (instance of
>   org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the referring class,
>   org/apache/axis/client/Stub, and the class loader (instance of
>   java/net/URLClassLoader) for the field's resolved type, sLoader, have
>   different Class objects for that type

Comment: *What* `LinkageError`?  Do not make us guess.

Comment: Sorry gentlemen,
This is the LinkageError:

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "service" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the referring class, org/apache/axis/client/Stub, and the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) for the field's resolved type, sLoader, have different Class objects for that type

Comment: this is deployment related issue,if you have multiple applications deployed, there might be duplicated jars (same class in two jars) and there might be dependencies in between those applications.